# How to get different error message using elesif

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I am working on one Login system which is send a verification link to the user and user have to verify within the one hour.

So When user click on verification link. I get user id and the code form url.

So by using this First i Will check is it correct or not form database. This is the query.

```
  $query = $this->db
        ->select('id,expiry_time')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->where('code', $code)
        ->get('candidate');
    $data = $query->row_array();
```

So I have to check if user has excluded the expiry_time limit or not so i use elseif.

```
if ($data === null) {
      echo "Verification code not correct";
} elseif ($data['expiry_time'] < $expiry_time) {
      echo "Your verification Time is expire ";
} else {
      echo "Code is correct & Time is Not Expire yet";
}
```

So here i am facing a problem. I did not get the proper message.

I want Separate Message if code is not correct & if time is expire.
I am little confused about it so if you suggest any correct way of getting proper error message than please tell me. 
Thanks.

Comment: I think You are just too much confused right now. your code looks correct. You just have to understand the else if process.

Comment: I used null because i get it in the var_dump. is that not proper or the correct way of checking the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ElesIf Loop Looks Correct. I Think You Need to Understand it first.

so this first if the condition

```
if ($data === null) {
  echo "Verification code not correct";
}
```

Here I know why you use Null but you can do if with the [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) also. 
So if your user code is not correct then you can return this message to the view.

```
if (empty($data) {
   return $code_incorrect; //Your Code incorrect message
}
```

Now If code is correct but time is expire then the [elseif](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) gives you the error message regarding this.

```
elseif ($data['expiry_time'] < $expiry_time) {
    return $time_expire;  // Your Time Expire message for user.
}
```

If code is correct and time expire you get error message of expiry and if code is incorrect then you get the error message for code incorrect.

now then else statement

```
else {
  return $sucess; //sucess message thet code is correct and time is not expire yet
 }
```

Here you can get the success message if both the condition is true.

This is the syntax of elseif

```
   if (condition) {
     code to be executed if this condition is **true**;
   } elseif (condition) {
     code to be executed if this condition is **true**;
   } else {
      code to be executed if all conditions are **false**;
   }
```

I hope You Understand it properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (empty($data)) {
        echo "Verification code not correct";
    } elseif ($data['expiry_time'] < $expiry_time) {
        echo "Your verification Time is expire ";
    } else {
        echo "Code is correct & Time is Not Expire yet";
    }
```

Your array isn't NULL, it's empty. It's being set, but there's nothing in it.

**EDIT**

Or, for learning purposes, in your model, use:

```
if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
    return NULL;
} else {
    $data = $query->row_array()
}
```

That would make your original controller (or view) return the correct message, but it isn't the most elegant way of handling it.

Comment: Thanks @Joe your I will keep in mind you suggestion. Thanks